# problem with arrays and operations result beign asaigned to values

Tags: python, python-2.6

Here is the python code :

```
x=[2, 3, 5, 7]
for i in range(1, 5000):
    if i%2:
        if i%3:
            if i%5:
                if i%7:
                    x.append(i)
x.remove(1)
a = 6
b = 2
for i in range(0, 10):
    a = x[a - b]
    b = x[a] - x[b]
```

I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` for some reason, even though x[] is 1360 and a is just 6 while b is 2 so I dont know why it is happening. Any help would be nice.
I am using the python shell. Would that be a problem?

Comment: We would need more code to help you out, can you put in more code & maybe give more explanation, also your code should be indented :)

Comment: Specify the code defining what is `x`, `a`, `b`. We cannot help you if there is no full code.

Comment: @decoddecod it is better now, are you sure about x.remove(1) line indentation ? As per my understanding you are trying to get list of numbers which are divisble by 2,3,5,7 right ? Then can you explain why are you doing x.remove(1)

Comment: yea 1 is not a prime so I removed it .I know it is not the nicest code but it works

Comment: @decoddecod is this the full code ? where is a & b defined? Also your first if is not indented

Comment: You will get `a = 11` and `b = 12` after the first iteration. So after second iteration, `a` = `x[11 - 12]` = `x[-1]` = `4999`. Because `len(x) = 1146`, using index of 4999 causes `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is your logic in the for loop.

You see:-

```
a = 6
b = 2
    for i in range(0, 10):
        a = x[a - b]
        b = x[a] - x[b]
```

Yes a was 6 & b was 2, but then when you enter your for loop for the first time, 
a's value is

x[a-b] which is x[6-2]

i.e. x[4] which gives you 11

so a's value is 11, likewise for b,

```
b = x[a] - x[b] # which translates to x[11] - x[2]
```

which becomes b=32 & the loop goes on jumping/changing the values of a & b which leads you to `IndexError: list index out of range` which is expected.

Try executing your program in pycharm & debug it, you would understand it better, or maybe just put some print statements.

I could not type so much in a comment, hence posted it as an answer.